# Android emulator does not show and loads fully

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have android 4.4.2 emulator. I have created and started it load properly but when I start that again or next days it loads successfully but does not shows when I click on that in task bar in Windows.

Can anyone have this problem and any work around for this?

Thanks,
Sivalingaraja

Comment: are you using eclipse juno?

Comment: from your avd manager try to create new one and check it will work

Comment: Yes I am using Juno only.

Comment: As I mentioned already if I create new avd it works perfect. But suppose if I starting yesterday created avd it gives this problem.

Comment: is it showing anything in logcat or console?

Comment: Go to DDMS-->Open Devices Tab--> Reset ADB from drop down option on right corner.

Comment: Yes it showing logs as normal avd runs.

Comment: is that anything related to adb mapping to old sdk path?